# Angularfire Auth session persistence

Tags: angularjs, firebase, angularfire

This is my first time using AngularJs, not sure whether my authentication handle correctly or not.  
I expect `$firebaseAuth()` will keep the authentication status even if I refresh the app. But every time I refresh the app, `$firebaseAuth()` will not re-authenticate the user, and I need to re-login. 
I read through the document and search in the source code, but can't find the function that allows me to configure the session persistence. Only 2 parameters `email` and `password` are accepted.

versions: 
angularjs v1.4.10 
angularfire v2.0.1 
firebase v3.0.3

my `authenticationService` litcoffee script

```
app.factory "authenticationService", [
    "$firebaseAuth"
    "$location"
    "$rootScope"
    ($firebaseAuth, $location, $rootScope) ->
        login: (email, password, redirectUrl = "/") ->
            $rootScope.authObj.$signInWithEmailAndPassword(email, password)
            .then(
                (firebaseUser) ->
                    console.log firebaseUser
                    $rootScope.firebaseUser = firebaseUser
                    return true

                (error) ->
                    $rootScope.firebaseUser = null
                    console.log error
                    alert error.message
                    return false
            )

        logout: (redirectUrl = "/login") ->
            $rootScope.authObj.$signOut()
            $location.path redirectUrl

        isLogged: () ->
            if $rootScope.authObj.$getAuth()
                return true
            else    
                return false

]
```

I check user authentication status on a controller which will call `authenticationService.isLogged()`, it will redirect to login page if user is not logged. 
What I want to achieve is just a simple authentication, user will remain authentication status even if they refresh. 
Please correct my if I'm on the wrong direction. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's my fault actually.
Firebase and AngularFire keep the authentication session persistence by default.
What I did wrong is check the authentication status immediately when the page loaded. At the moment AngularFire hasn't fired yet, it will take some time to re-authenticate the application.

Thus, [$firebaseAuth.$onAuthStateChanged](http://www.google.com) can be very helpful.
Listen to it when your page loaded. Once the event fired, it will notify you whether the user authenticated.

Comment: Man, U'r a Master of Puppets! Unfortunately the documentation has [`$onAuth(callback[, context])`](https://www.firebase.com/docs/web/libraries/angular/api.html#angularfire-users-and-authentication-onauthcallback-context) Instead of this there is `$onAuthStateChanged` in keys of `$firebaseAuth()`.